# Swift PDFKit - PDFAnnotation button not displaying text

Tags: swift, ios-pdfkit

I am trying to build a table of contents in a PDF in swift. My button is not displaying any text, though the bounds and background color is displaying.

```
let anno: PDFAnnotation  = PDFAnnotation(bounds: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: 300, height: 40), forType: .widget, withProperties: nil)

anno.widgetFieldType = .button
anno.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
anno.fontColor = UIColor.black
anno.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
anno.destination = PDFDestination()
anno.fieldName = "Button Third try"
anno.widgetStringValue = "button hello?"
anno.caption = "This is a test button"
            
anno.draw(with: PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox, in: context.cgContext)
```

Ultimately I want to click on a link which goes to a page in my Pdf Document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `widgetControlType` to `.pushButtonControl`:

`anno.widgetControlType = .pushButtonControl`

There's [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdf_widgets) demonstrating adding widgets to a PDF that's worth checking out.

Comment: So my mistake was I tried that before and it didn't work, but I hadn't realized I needed to set BOTH widgetFieldType to button, and widgetControlType to pushButtonControl. Thanks for your help. Edit: Now the text is upside down, but I've seen that solution else where.